# Is it possible to have an order limit in Shopify per user per month?

Tags: shopify

We have a specific usecase where on a shopify website we need users to purchase only a certain limit e.g 200 USD. They can order multiple times, multiple orders in a month but the final amount cannot go beyond 200USD. If it does, at any point, it should throw an error and not let the user proceed.
Is this possible on Shopify?

Thanks,
Vrushali

The tech team came back saying this cannot be done. Hence asking the larger community for an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the tech team is right to an extent. Shopify doesn't provide this feature out-of-the-box.

What can be done is to create a custom solution using Shopify's API on your company's end. The custom code could track the total amount spent by each customer within a given time frame and prevent them from proceeding with the checkout if the limit is exceeded.

Implementing this control flow will give your company the ultimate freedom, allowing you to control the rate limits per customer effectively.

Additionally, there may be third-party apps available on the Shopify store that offer order management features. Some of these apps might provide functionalities to set spending limits for customers or restrict the number of orders they can place within a specific timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cart and Checkout validation api from Shopify functions and disallow/ allow customer checkout based on their "Amountspent"

https://shopify.dev/docs/api/functions/reference/cart-checkout-validation

It will be a one time setup as shopify released extension only apps few days ago and works as native.